# How to display values form a python program output in a Swing GUI developed in Java

Tags: java, python, swing

I am trying to create a graphical user interface (GUI) using Swing in Java.

The part I am kind of stuck is, I am planning to display some values from my Python program to the interface I am developing in Swing. I have looked up in forums and came across the Jython thing, but not quite sure on how to proceed with this, anyone information in this issue would be helpful to me.

Some extra information, if it may help, I have a set of sensors reading some values using a Raspberry Pi, and the sensors are operated using a Python script running in RPi. Now my goal is to develop a GUI using Java so that I can display those values from the Python script to the swing interface.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think your easiest path forward would be to store the values that are collected by the Raspberry Pi in an intermediary storage.  This can be as simple as a text file, or if you want something more verbose, you can store it in a RDBMS or NoSQL DB.  Then it becomes easier for the java application to look up the values without having to interface with Python.

If you want to directly interface with Python, you could look into [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/languages/python/) which has limited ability to directly execute Python code.